# cpan getting killed when installing Log::Log4perl

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install the perl module `Log::Log4perl` on a basic Digital Ocean server through Ubuntu as a backup tool I'm trying to use depends on it but it keeps saying "Killed".  **Could anyone with experience with cpan provide some guidiance on where I can find a log file telling me what the problem is?**

```
$ cpan Log::Log4perl
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Sat, 27 Jun 2015 12:17:02 GMT
  HTTP::Date not available
..............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.10) available.
  [Currently running version is v2.00]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


............Killed
```

Comment: Is it running out of memory?  You might try using [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that this is a resource issue and it looks like other people have had [similar](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=214426) [issues](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=781809) with this as well.  At the point in the run that you're showing, CPAN is trying to slurp that entire 02packages.details.txt.gz file into memory which is causing your OS to kill the process.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11110491/21987) for instructions on how to use cpanm, or you could try downloading the module as a gz and run `perl Makefile.PL && make && make install`.

Comment: in short, use cpanm (in Ubuntu the package is called cpanminus, and the way of installing a module is: cpanm Log::Log4perl)

Comment: how to do on arch?

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely running out of memory. I have had this issue when using a VM with 1GB of RAM and adding some swap space fixes the problem.